# Pandas ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: EOF inside string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data that is over 400,000 lines long. When running this code:

```
f=pd.read_csv(filename,error_bad_lines=False)
```

I get the following error:

```
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: EOF inside string starting at row 454751
```

My data by the end of the file looks like this:

```
BTC 9948    8718    1.57E+12    ASK
BTC 52      8718    1.57E+12    ASK
BTC 120     8718    1.57E+12    ASK
BTC 200     8718    1.57E+12    ASK
BTC 150     8718    1.57E+12    ASK
BTC 50      8718    1.57E+12    ASK
BTC 10      8718    1.57E+12    ASK
BTC 57      8718    1.57E+12    ASK
BTC 50      8718    1.57E+12    ASK
BTC 50191   8718
```

Line 454751 is this one: `BTC  50      8718    1.57E+12    ASK`
I tried running `error_bad_lines=False` as seen above but that still  doesnt work. I also searched for quotes in my file but I do not have any.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Changing the Parser engine from C to Python should solve your problem. Use the following line to read your csv:

```
f = pd.read_csv(filename, error_bad_lines=False, engine="python")
```

From the [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) documentation:

> engine : *{‘c’, ‘python’}, optional*
>
> Parser engine to use. The C engine is faster while the python engine is currently more feature-complete.

Comment: This works, thanks! However, it processes the data but shows this error after each run `Skipping line 454752: unexpected end of data`

Comment: Have you found the reason or the solution for this? @AspiringCoder

Comment: Generally speaking, the handy thing with [temporary] swapping to the Python parser is that the Python parser may give a better idea of the underlying error. After fixing this, it's potentially possible to swap back to the C parser.

Answer (score 0):

please split and read file like below.

```
import pandas as pd

for chunk in pd.read_csv(filename, chunksize=<your_chunksize_here>)
    do_processing()
    train_algorithm()
```