# Pandas Error Tokenizing but when trouble shooting the data points are not separated

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When trying to open the file it gives me ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 8, saw 22152

What I tried:

```
mat = pd.read_csv('/Users/csb/Desktop/Zebrafish_scRNA/sample_Control_WTA_1_RSEC_MolsPerCell.csv', sep = '\t')
```

Output:

[image]

Instead of data points in each separate columns it got all combined

Output I want is:

[image]

The first 7 rows of Output dataframe dropped. Want to automate this since there will be several files which comes in that Output format.
How can I resolve this issue and automate it to get the output that I want to achieve?

Comment: you should try to change the parse engine as decribe here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60345503/pandas-parsererror-error-tokenizing-data-c-error-eof-inside-string

Comment: Use skiprows=7 in the read_csv to drop the first 7 rows